# Custom "base" ngResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, parse-platform, ngresource

I'm new to Angular and am looking to see if [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/7HcFZ/) can still be done with the current version of angular and ngResource.

In particular, I like how in that example, they set the http headers for the entire resource and not each resource action. Is that possible in the current angular resource?

Another thing I like is the use of the `response` option. I'm using the parse.com rest api for my data store and so a query returns a single object with an array in the `results` key. Right now the way I've gotten around this is by using the `transformResponse` option for the query action. But that means I'm having to `JSON.parse` the data and the return the `.results` value. It just seems like a bit of a hack that I was thinking could be done cleaner, as it is in that old example.

The last thing I like about that example is the use of `internalize` and `externalize` to tweak the json object.

Is it still possible to accomplish any of these things in the current angular resource library?

I know I can use `$http.defaults.headers` or use an `http interceptor` for setting the http headers, but I'd rather have them contained in a custom Resource just for parse.com interactions if possible.

Comment: are you looking for a generic ngResource where you can change settings?

Comment: Looking for a generic resource where I can set the http headers for all requests, and if possible do something like the internalize and externalize in the fiddle I linked to. It would be great to "transform" my data to be more standardized, for example have an id property instead of _id or objectId.

Comment: I think http interceptor is the best place to do it, I didnt get the reason why you dont want http interceptor's??

Comment: It just seemed cleaner to do it all in the custom resource. That way everything to do with accessing the parse REST API would be in one place. For now I have used an HTTP interceptor. But it is in one file, and the rest of my parse REST API interactions are in another. So it seems a little disconnected this way.

Comment: may be you can write the logic for changing the http headers in the method in the same service where you are customizing the ngResource. and use that service as dependency in http interceptor. this way your all logic would be in one place.